# Can't add a file to an XCode Project

Tags: xcode

Well there are two problems both have to do with the restrictive file select dialog.

In one case it is a library sitting in a ".lib" directory and the other is some C source code inside an application bundle.

Any ideas? Unfortunately the files in the application bundle are generated by another compiler (which compiles to C files) to i can't simply copy them elsewhere.

I'm using XCode 3.0

Answer (score 7, accepted):

a) Drag & Drop instead of using the File dialog

b) Use Cmd+Shift+G inside the file select dialog and type in the path of the directory containing your file